# How to calculate the data size of the Mongodb collection using Java MongoOperations?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

Mongodb has a mongo shell command `db.getCollection('myCollection').dataSize()` to return the data size of the given collection. However, this does not work with MongoOperations `getCollections()` in Spring.

To work around this is what I tried :

```
myMongoOpObject.executeCommand("db.getCollection(collectionName).dataSize()");
```

However, this does not work. No errors or console prints. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `collStats` command, see here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/collStats/

```java
Document stats = operations.executeCommand(new Document("collStats", "collectionName"));
System.out.println(stats.get("count"));
System.out.println(stats.get("avgObjSize"))
System.out.println(stats.get("storageSize"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Use below syntax

```
 List<MyCollection> list = mongoOperation.findAll(MyCollection.class);
 System.out.println("Number of records = " + list.size());
```

Comment: he wants the byte size of the collection as stored in mongodb